# Java Generic Type Variables

Tags: java, generics

My question is about type variables used in generic classes and methods.

Why can't we do something like this `T = new T();` or in other words, why can't we construct an object of the type variable ?

I know that generic information is erased during compilation, and everything is converted to
Object, so why doesn't the compiler assume that `T` is an object and let us construct it ?

Comment: This is a good question. It illustrates some of the drawbacks inherent in Java Generics and some leaks in the abstraction. Incidentally, you also cannot create an array `T[]` for the same reason -- type erasure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that at runtime the JVM does not know which class the `T` actually stands for (that information is not retained at runtime, that's what "type erasure" means). Therefore the JVM just sees that you want to construct a new `T`, but has no idea which constructor to actually invoke - hence it's not allowed.

There are workarounds, but it will not work as you propose.

> why doesn't the compiler assume that T
>   is an object and let us construct it
>   ??

Well, of course the runtime could just construct an instance of `java.lang.Object` for you, but that would not really help, as you really wanted a `T`.

Comment: one thing, does the runtime see T or Object, isn't the generic information erased, ??

Comment: I don't know what the runtime "sees", as I don't know how this is implemented internally. I believe it just does not see any type at all. It can probably distinguish between cases where there is really "Object" written in the code, and cases where a type was erased.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to sleske's answer; if you need to create objects of T inside your generic class, the solution is to pass a `Class<T>` reference as argument to either the constructor or the method that needs to create new objects and use that class to create new instances.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by "there are workarounds". Thanks for adding it :-).

Comment: I don't condone this approach, but if you like to write really hacky code, you can still work around it using reflection.  `((ParametrizedType)getClass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0].createNewInstance()`.  This assumes a default constructor of course.